# URL Data won't go inside SQL database Python

Tags: python, sql, database, api

```
import json
import urllib
import sqlite3

import temp

def loading():
    url = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1'  # URL for API 1-5json_obj = urllib.urlopen(url)
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(response)  # loads the url and set it into data variable

    for item in data[0].keys():
        print(item)
        return data  # Get the keys
# def loading():
# print " LOADING API(s)"
# urllib.urlopen('https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1')
# temp = json.dumps(data[1])
# print (json.dumps(data[1]))
# print (" ")
def createDB(data):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('comp.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    # Create table
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comp
        (description text, title text, url text, company_logo text, company text, id integer primary key, company_url text, how_to_apply text,
        location text, type text, created_at timestamp)''')
    temp_values = list(tuple())
    for item in data:
        print (item)
        list_of_values = [v for k, v in item.items()]
        tuple_of_values = tuple(list_of_values)
        temp_values.append(tuple_of_values)
        c.executemany('INSERT INTO comp VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', temp_values)
        #TO DO
        # Make sub sets for each category call
        # put in category for each ? in table


def main():
    data = loading()
    createDB(data)

main()
```

No data from url being stored into the sql database such (title, url, name ect..) 
I get this error

File "/Users/issac_rodriguez/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint2/database.py", line 36, in createDB
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO comp VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', temp_values)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch

Comment: You don't provide the actual data you're using, so it's hard to say for sure, but likely the problem is that some item in `list_of_values` is the wrong data type.  For example, the sixth item must be an integer and the eleventh item must be a timestamp.  Are those items of the correct type?

Comment: Also, it seems like the call to `executemany()` is indented too far -- it makes more sense to have it run once, after the for loop is finished gathering up all the data.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this and here is how I made it work.

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comp
        (id text primary key, type text, url text,created_at timestamp, company text, company_url text, location text, title text, description text, how_to_apply text, company_logo text
        )''')
```

I changed the position of database's columns names to match the returned data from Github

```
for item in data:
    list_of_values = [v for k, v in item.items()]
    tuple_of_values = tuple(list_of_values)
    temp_values.append(tuple_of_values)

c.executemany('INSERT INTO comp VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', temp_values)
conn.commit()
```

I took the `executemany` outside of the `for` loop and `commit()` the changes at the end.

Here is the whole file. I am using Python 3 if you aren't then you should keep `import urllib` instead of `from urllib import request`

```
import json
from urllib import request
import sqlite3


def loading():
    url = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1'  # URL for API 1-5json_obj = urllib.urlopen(url)
    response = request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(response)  # loads the url and set it into data variable

    for item in data[0].keys():
        return data  # Get the keys
# def loading():
# print " LOADING API(s)"
# urllib.urlopen('https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1')
# temp = json.dumps(data[1])
# print (json.dumps(data[1]))
# print (" ")
def createDB(data):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('comp.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    # Create table
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comp
        (id text primary key, type text, url text,created_at timestamp, company text, company_url text, location text, title text, description text, how_to_apply text, company_logo text
        )''')
    temp_values = list(tuple())
    for item in data:
        list_of_values = [v for k, v in item.items()]
        tuple_of_values = tuple(list_of_values)
        temp_values.append(tuple_of_values)


        #TO DO
        # Make sub sets for each category call
        # put in category for each ? in table
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO comp VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', temp_values)
    conn.commit()

def main():
    data = loading()
    createDB(data)

main()
```

Comment: @ine-io I tried pasting your code into my file but I still have the same error not sure what I'm doing wrong on my end?

Comment: @ine-io anyway you could send the .py file you used?

Comment: @istackz I edited my answer to include the file's content.

Comment: @ine-io I still get this error   File "/Users/issac_rodriguez/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint2/database.py", line 40, in main
    data = loading()
  File "/Users/issac_rodriguez/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint2/database.py", line 9, in loading
    data = json.load(response)  # loads the url and set it into data variable
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load'

Comment: That's weird because `json` module has `load` function. You probably have a custom module named `json` and you are importing it instead of python `json` module. You can test loading function [here](https://repl.it/languages/python3) Copy and paste `loading` function and print its result to see that it actually works.

Comment: Glad to see it working for once for me lol, not to be a pain but anyway of running it in pycharm?

Comment: I've never used Pycharm editor. For me I called the file from a terminal and it worked perfectly.